# Make a call and play a message? (Android 1.6)

Tags: android, phone-call, android-1.6-donut

I have an application that will need to make a call and play a recorded message. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry. You can initiate a call with the right permission, but you have no way to play the recorded message.