# Put some message in a call from android app

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a call from my android app using the code below

```
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
                startActivity(callIntent);
```

Now i'm able to make a call from my device successfully but my requirement is that when the receiver of call (i.e. phone with number 123456789 )....picks the call he should be able to hear some custom message.....this custom message i should be able to give from my andriod app .....is it possible ?...any ideas ?

Comment: Sounds interesting.. :-)

Comment: [I don't think this is possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764057/make-a-call-and-play-a-message-android-1-6) ... There is no way that Android would allow to record or write to the call stream.